# How do I set a different color background for photo gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a photo gallery project and want to set a different color background for each image. I have a total of six images and as of now the background for all images is pink. I have tried adding another .popup class(the class containing my images) in the CSS with a new background color but that did not work. I have also tried using getElementsByClassName in the JavaScript to change the color when the user clicks on the left or right arrow, which did change the color form pink to another color. However, it did not allow me to set a color for each background. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];



const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i+1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i+1}`;
    index = i;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
    }
})
const setPopupImage = index => {
  
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
setPopupImage(0);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus{
  outline: none;
}

body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7a2d;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery{
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image{
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}



.popup{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background:  pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bk{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: brown;
}


.popup.active{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name{
  opacity: 0;
}


  

.close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow{
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow{
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
       
        <div class="top-bar">
            <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
            <span class="close-btn">
                <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
            </span>
        </div>
      
        <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        
        <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">
       
        <h1 class="index">01</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="bk"
            ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the selector `:nth-child(n)` in the CSS file. [Here's a link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.php) for better explanation.

```css
.gallery-image:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
} 

.gallery-image:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.gallery-image:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}
```

If this is not what you're looking for, let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it!  Unfortunately, your code did not work, it did not change the color of the backgrounds. I believe your idea of using an :nth-child(n) is headed in the right direction but something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a photo and it opens in a popup modal, the background of the modal will be different each time. When you click the left or right arrow the background color will change again.

In your JS code I add this line

```
randomBackgroundColor(); //<-- NEW LINE
```

The function `randomBackgroundColor()` sets a different color to the background of the popup element.

I hope I have been helpful

**Example:**

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');

        randomBackgroundColor(); //<-- NEW LINE
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i + 1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i + 1}`;
    index = i;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (index > 0) {
        updateImage(index - 1);
        randomBackgroundColor(); //<-- NEW LINE
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (index < images.length - 1) {
        updateImage(index + 1);
        randomBackgroundColor(); //<-- NEW LINE
    }
})

const setPopupImage = index => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
}

setPopupImage(0);



function randomBackgroundColor() {
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    let color = 'rgb(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ')';

    popup.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #ff7a2d;
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
    width: 80%;
    height: 90vh;
    max-width: 1600px;
    max-height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
    width: 30%;
    height: calc(50% - 20px);
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: 1s;
}



.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: pink;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.bk {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: brown;
}


.popup.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: turquoise;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
    opacity: 0;
}


.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
    left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
    right: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    object-fit: contain;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">

    <div class="top-bar">
        <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
        <span class="close-btn">
            <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
        </span>
    </div>

    <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>

    <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">

    <h1 class="index">01</h1>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
        <div class="bk"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
</div>
```